# Class 'Post' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Trying to delete data from database. But "Class not found" error showing.
Here is my code for the delete.

```
Route::get('/delete', function (){

    $post = Post::find(1);
    $post->delete();

});
```

[This is my post class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmidx.png)

Comment: have you got a use clause eg use App\Models\Post; or whatever it is namespaced as?

Comment: Route::get() shouldn't be changing the resource, you should use Route::delete() instead, then provide the id of the resource to delete.

Comment: Also, why are you placing control login within a routing closure?

Answer (score 1):

> The HTTP verbs (or methods, as they are properly called) are POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE. These correspond to create, read, update, and delete (or CRUD) operations, respectively. There are a number of other verbs, too, but are utilized less frequently. Of those less-frequent methods, OPTIONS and HEAD are used more often than others.

Deleting a resource should be done using The DELETE HTTP Verb.

in your case:

```
//include your posts model.
use App\Post; 

Route::delete('/delete/{id}', function ($id){

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->delete();

});
```

PS. you might consider implementing your app logic inside separate controllers instead of using your routes file.